# Produce repmat() method using java

Tags: java, matlab

we have the `repmat(arr,2,1,2)` method in matlab produce a format which is :
`arr = [6,3,9,0];`

```
 L(:,:,1) =
 6 3 9 0 
 6 3 9 0

  L(:,:,2) = 
  6 3 9 0 
  6 3 9 0
```

the java code that i tried to produce same format is

```
class test24{
     public static void main ( String [] args ) {
       int[] arr = {6,3,9,0};
       test24 test = new test24();
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(test.repmat(arr,2,1,2)));
     }
   public static int[][][] repmat (int[] array, int rows, int columns, int        depth)
  {
       int arrayColumns = array.length;
       int resultColumns = arrayColumns * columns;

      int[][][] result = new int[rows][resultColumns][depth];

    int z = 0;
    for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++)
         {
       for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
           {
        for (int c = 0; c < resultColumns; c++)
           {
          result[r][c][d] = array[z++];

          if (z >= arrayColumns)
            {
            z = 0;

          }
        }
      }
     }
    return result;
    }
}
```

the the result from the java code is :

> [[6,6],[3,3],[9,9],[0,0]],[[[6,6],[3,3],[9,9],[0,0]]???

please any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `depth` argument causes that each value within the array has two values (`int[][][] result = new int[rows][resultColumns][depth];` would become (given the inputs rows=2, columns=1 and depth=2 and an initial array of 4) `new int[2][1][2]`).

Not entirely sure what the `repmat` method exactly should do put it might be that changing the creation of the array into `int[][][] result = new int[depth][rows][resultColumns];` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that this is because MATLAB used [column-major indexing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Row-major_order) whereas Java uses [Iliffe vectors](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Iliffe_vector). So MATLAB stores multidimensional vectors using a single contiguous block of memory where Java stores an array of pointers and each pointer points to another array.

It's difficult to tell exactly what the Java data-structure your code resulted in was. Do you think maybe you could rather post a screen shot from a debugger? What you have now does not look correct, the brackets don't even match.

At a guess though, I would suggest that you maybe change this line

```
result[r][c][d] = array[z++];
```

To something more like

```
result[d][r][c] = array[z++];
```

Or possibly to even alter the inner loop to something like

```
for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    result[d][r][c] = array;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing saying that Java does not store arrays in contigous memory blocks. Iliffe vectors can definitely be stored in contigous memory as well. While accessed via pointers it is for example possible in C to access arrays by incrementing the pointer (`int i[2,2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}}; printf("%d", i[3])` where `i[3] == *(i+3)` ). It is nothing that says that Java have the same implementation of Iliffe vectors though. The problem should rather be column-major vs. row-major order and a separate problem is that multidimensional arrays require other ways to access data than C does.

Comment: @patrik if the issue is row-major ordering then `result[d][r][c] = array[z++];` is still the fix

Comment: @patrik btw I did start out this answer as a row-major vs column-major answer, but the wiki article that I linked to (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Row-major_order) states that Java uses Illife vectors (which I had not heard of before) which is why I changed it to state that.

Comment: Iliffe vectors does not enforce data alignment. It simpliy specifies that the data is stored in an array of arrays. My point is that you wrote "So MATLAB stores multidimensional vectors using a **single contiguous block of memory** where Java stores an array of pointers and each pointer points to another array". The actual data can still be contigous. C stores the data pointed to as a contigous array, but uses Iliffe vectors to store the addresses. Incrementing the pointer to the first memory position will access the elements in row major order. The point is minor, but still siginficant.